# Kivy : Relative size of text displaying in a popup

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Is there any way to make the message/title in the label fits into the popup ?

'`message`' or '`title`' can be a long text that goes beyond the borders of the popup .

```
   def popup_display(self, title, message):

        btnclose = Button(text='Close me', size_hint_y=None, height=50)

        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        content.add_widget(Label(text=message))
        content.add_widget(btnclose)

        popup = Popup(content=content, title=title,
                      size_hint=(None, None), 
                      size=(300, 300),
                      auto_dismiss=False)

        btnclose.bind(on_release=popup.dismiss)

        popup.open()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Label` has a `text_size` property, which allows to constraint its size to given bounding box. You can bind it to available size:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from functools import partial 

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(on_press=partial(self.popup_display, "title", "bar "*80))

    def popup_display(self, title, message, widget):
        btnclose = Button(text='Close me', size_hint_y=None, height=50)
        l = Label(text=message)
        l.bind(size=lambda s, w: s.setter('text_size')(s, w))

        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        content.add_widget(l)
        content.add_widget(btnclose)
        popup = Popup(content=content, title=title, size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300), auto_dismiss=False)
        btnclose.bind(on_release=popup.dismiss)

        popup.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Text that won't fit will get removed. If you want to have it all you should use `ScrollView` inside of your popup.

As for title, it's not a Label but a string, so the best you can do is to add newlines:

```
return Button(on_press=partial(self.popup_display, "multiline\ntitle", "bar "*80))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here'a a simpler version without BoxLayout and Button:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(on_press=partial(self.popup_display, "title", "bar "*80))

    def popup_display(self, title, message, widget):
        l = Label(text=message)
        l.bind(size=lambda s, w: s.setter('text_size')(s, w))

        popup = Popup(content=l, title=title, size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 200), auto_dismiss=True)

        popup.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image: Popup result]

Simply click outside the popup to close it.